# OpenGL programming in C++: anti-aliasing

Tags: c++, opengl, antialiasing

I am quite newbie in OpenGL and all my knowledge comes from tutorials in the Internet. For now I can program rotating cube lighted by point source. My new goal is to implement antialiasing - possibly without any magical techniques like a hypothetical `glEnable(Smooth_Lines)` function. The method I'm using currently does not work.

[image: Example of program output!]

My first attempt was to try `glAccum` function and implement jittering anti-aliasing - I don't know if this is not possible on my Radeon graphic card or I just wrote something wrong.

My second attempt is to use `glGenFrameBuffers` (and rest of family). But now (after ~10 hours of research) I just don't have any strength to continue. Can you tell me where I should implement antialiasing process? Or which functions should I use? Here is cutted version of my whole code:

```
    class Window;
    static Window* ptr;

    class Window{


    GLuint vbo[4],program;
    GLint att[5],mvp,mvp2;

    void init_res(){

    a0=glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    GLfloat cube[]= ... something
    GLfloat colors[]= ... still something
    GLushort elements[]= ... oh you can just guess how it should look :)

//now I am binding buffers and send cube data to shaders

    program=glCreateProgram();

//little more code here

    }
    void Draw(){
// here is subfunction for drawing all cube. 
    }

    void onDisplay(){

//here is main function which is send to glutDisplayFunc

    Draw();

//should I add something here?

    glutSwapBuffers();

    }

    Window(int s_w,int s_h){
    glutInit(&ac, av);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_ALPHA|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(s_w, s_h);
    glutCreateWindow("My Rotating Cube");
    glewInit();
    init_res();
    ptr=this;
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(Idle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Key);

    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//here is a lot of garbage - you can call it 'voodoo programming'

    glutMainLoop();
    free_resources();
    }

    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ac=argc;
    av=argv;
    Window *okno;
    okno = new Window(800,600);
    }
```

For now, everything in this program works (well, before cuts of course :P ). I did not attach shaders - they are as simple as it is possible (with lighting and added cube borders).

Any ideas how to implement anti-aliasing here?

Comment: Have you tried using MSAA (multy simple anti-aliasing) it's pretty easy to add, you have to look for it in your API ypu are using wich is glut.

Comment: What is your goal for the anti-aliasing? Do you only need it to get smoother edges for your geometry? In that case, enabling MSAA, as suggested by @user42813, should be simple and effective. If you for example generate sharp transitions in your fragment shader, MSAA won't help. It really depends on the specific use case. The reason there are so many different approaches to anti-aliasing is that there are a lot of tradeoffs, and none of them are ideal for all cases.

Comment: @user42813: Multi-sample ;) The way you wrote it made me laugh, sorry to say. It's not really simple at all, it introduces a variable number of samples generated during rasterization. SSAA is actually simpler, but slower too.

Comment: Andon M. Coleman: silly me, im not english so i wrote stuff the way i spell them ;), if speed matter then FXAA can do the job, but it requires offscreen rendering and one more shader pass.